# How to browse a website as if I am in USA?

Tags: ssh, proxy, ssh-tunneling, http-proxy

I am in Taiwan right now and whenever I go to a website that I could browse in USA, it directly transfers me to the Asia site.  There is no way to browse the USA version of the site, probably because they want to hide how much the merchandise is selling in USA.

So how can I use a proxy server to be able to browse the USA site?  Or since I could `ssh` into my dreamhost account (which is in USA or Canada), can't I just do some `ssh` command and then browse as if I am sitting at a dreamhost computer to browse the website?  I tried `ssh -X myusername@myhost.com` and then start `firefox &` except I think dreamhost doesn't have firefox installed and so it can't send a firefox window over by X11.

Comment: What is the connection between this question and  Unix and Linux?

Comment: about `ssh` and tunneling... or can I start some command on the dreamhost shell and make it a proxy for myself?

Comment: As this is not a *specific* Unix question, you would get more visibility on superuser.com, I suggest you migrate this question there

Answer (score 3):

With

```
ssh -D 8080 yourserver
```

you can start a SOCKS proxy to your home server. Configure your client to use `localhost:8080` as SOCKS proxy.

This method requires that port forwarding is enabled, see the `AllowTcpForwarding` directive in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

If you can not enable the TCP forwarding you might have a look at `sshuttle`. See http://linux.die.net/man/8/sshuttle for the manual page. This way you can setup a proxy based VPN over `ssh` using Python (version >=2.3).

Example:

```
/usr/sbin/sshuttle --dns -D --pidfile /tmp/sshuttle.pid -x <localsubnet> -r myuser@server <subnets-to-vpn>
```

Comment: so you mean on my local machine (my Macbook), I type `ssh -D 8080 myusername@myserver.com` which will actually log me in at myserver.com and give me a Bash.  And then change the Web Proxy HTTP and HTTPS on my Macbook to `localhost:8080`?  Can't make it to work so far... for one thing, I think my dreamhost machine is not running a proxy program that can help forward the traffic yet?

Comment: (by the way, I have to type in a password to log into myserver.com... so no ssh key is set up yet... does that make a difference?)

Comment: You indeed start `ssh -D 8080 myusername@myserver.com` which should log you on and present you a shell. In another terminal on your client, view the output of `netstat -an|grep 8080` to see if the local listener is started. If not, verify if `AllowTcpForwarding` is enabled in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on `myserver.com`. Set it to `yes` and reload the `ssh` service on `myserver.com`. If you have the listener than configure your client's browser to use a SOCKS proxy and use `localhost` for the host and `8080` as the proxy port. See also `man ssh` and especially the `-D` option.

Comment: @Lambert, you should edit your answer to include the information in the last comment. Also I'd mention that on a hosted account with ssh access (such as the OP has), changing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Hola better internet" extension for Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [zebedee](http://www.winton.org.uk/zebedee/) in a USA VPS or dedicate and install squid beside it , then install zebedee client then enjoy it.
Server side of it:

```
zebedee -s -U
```

But you have to write a config file for client:

```
server false
localsource true
multiuse true
tunnel 81:IP_OF_SERVER:3128
compression zlib:9
detached true
```

You can use localhost:81 in your browser.
For runnung in client side, you can `zebedee -f yourconfigfile`